# Why cannot I show docker repo in local registry via web API after restarting registry:v2?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Below are steps to reproduce the issue.

**docker --version**

Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6

**docker images | grep centos**

centos                           latest              3fa822599e10        3 weeks ago         204MB

**docker tag centos:latest 127.0.0.1:5000/centos**

**docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/centos**

The push refers to a repository [127.0.0.1:5000/centos]

d1be66a59bc5: Pushed

latest: digest: 
sha256:3a32a170c945ffe18334b3f514fcb66f9c14001b2266c9ed8504c72db0acde11 size: 529

**docker ps**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES

046a5d68c8b2        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   festive_wozniak

**curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog**

{"repositories":["centos"]}      ***-----We can list 'centos' repo after pushing.***

**docker stop 046a5d68c8b2**

046a5d68c8b2

**docker run -p 5000:5000 -d registry:2**

bad6ec7aad590f91aaf1721703ce6468e8254d159e56a5b5f018e5e3c25cf7e0

**curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog**

{"repositories":[]}   ***---- after restarting registry, we cannot see 'centos' info***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each **docker run** creates a new container.

To restart a container you can either run `docker start 046a5d68c8b2` (following your example) or use the `--restart=always` option to docker run.

See:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies-restart

Comment: Make sense. Thank you for the help.